# Get real GPS coordinates out of known edges values on python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to find a way to convert pixels into a real coordinates. I have an image with known (GPS) edges values.

- Top left = 43.51281, -70.46223
- Top right = 43.51279, -70.46213
- Bottom left = 43.51272, -70.46226
- Bottom right = 43.51270, -70.46215

Image with known edges values

[image]

I have another script that prints the coordinates in pixels of an image. Is there any way that the value of each corner is declared, and that it prints the real coordinates of where I clicked?

For example: The next image shape is [460, 573] and when I click somewhere on it, the pixels of that click are shown, I want it to be real coordinates.

Example

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

An option is to use OpenCV's `getPerspectiveTransform()` function, see this for an intuitive explanation of how the function maps real world coordinates to coordinates on another image (which in your case would be mapping the GPS values to the pixel values within the image):

https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-track-football-players-using-yolo-sort-and-opencv-6c58f71120b8

And these for an example of the function being used:

[Python Open CV perspectiveTransform()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27585355/python-open-cv-perspectivetransform)

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/perspective-transformation-python-opencv/

Comment: an affine transformation would be good enough

Comment: I read and researched perspective transformation with opencv. I was already using that, but with the part of the gps coordinates I still don't understand it. I saw examples that use image recognition to do it but never declare every corner with a known gps value. I am newbie to python by the way.